# How to disable drag and drop feature in ExtGWT

Tags: gxt

I am using EditorGrid in ExtGWT. currently DnD feature is enabled. i want desable in particular context. please help me how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can call DropTarget's disable() OR DragSource's disable() method to either disable Dragging OR Dropping.

You can also change the "group" field of DropTarget or DragSource (using setGroup) to have a mistmatch between both of them to disable DnD.